# Redefinition of noinline attribute using macros

Tags: c++, gcc, macros

Is it possible to redefine attributes such as `[[gnu::noinline]]` and `__attribute__((noinline))` using `#define`?

I am trying to accomplish this

```cpp
#define noinline __attribute__((noinline)) \

noinline void my_function();

// Turns into
__attribute__((noinline))
void my_function();
// or 
[[gnu::noinline]]
void my_function();
```

I have tried breaking the macro definition up, but I can't seem to outsmart GCC.

```cpp
#define noinline_ [gnu::noinline]
#define noinline [noinline_]
// and 
#define noinline_ __attribute__((
#define noinline noinline_ noinline))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to redefine attributes such as [[gnu::noinline]] and **attribute**((noinline)) using #define?

You cannot "redefine" them i.e. you cannot make them mean something else.

You can however define macro aliases for them which is the goal that you accomplished with your example.

Comment: My examples don’t compile. Should they? This is just for an Arduino project, so perhaps their version of GCC doesn’t allow it?

Comment: @Iain They compile just fine in my GCC.

Comment: Hmmm weird. I just tried the `arduino-cli` and it worked just fine.